# Which regex can select a html attribute and its UUID like value

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove attributes from a html string tags. I need a regex to remove at once all occurences of an attribute and its value which is an UUID in a String.replace function. Here is how they look like

```
<div imgid="f15213ee-9308-485e-a6df-b4c5746503e4" ></div>
<div imgid="rgrgrzze-ttee-485e-a6df-b4c5746503e4" ></div>
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this

```
var html = `
  <div imgid="f15213ee-9308-485e-a6df-b4c5746503e4" ></div>
  <div imgid="rgrgrzze-ttee-485e-a6df-b4c5746503e4" ></div>
`;

html = html.replace(/imgid="[^"]+"/g, '');
```